# By assigning prop variables to component variables they are linked

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

I assign a props variable to a component variable and when I change the component variable I change the props...

> Parent Component:

```
const prova = [
    {
      1: 'a'
    },
    {
      2: 'b'
    },
    {
      3: 'c'
    },
    {
      4: 'd'
    },
    {
      5: 'e'
    }
]

class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
   ...
   <ScrollHorizontalTwoColumns categories={prova} title="Your Categories" seeAll={true}/>
   ...
```

> Child component:

```
class ScrollHorizontalTwoColumns extends React.Component {

    categories1 = "";
    categories2 = "";

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.warn(this.props.categories);
      if (typeof this.props.categories === 'object' && this.props.categories.length > 0){

        this.categories1 = this.props.categories;
        this.categories2 = this.categories1.splice(0, Math.ceil(this.categories1.length / 2)) 

      }
      console.warn(this.props.categories);
    }
```

The second warn its different from the first warn...

[image: android]

Comment: I seem to be missing what your question/problem is.

Comment: @epascarello that objects are passed by reference. `.splice` messes up the Array he passes in `this.props.categories`

Comment: @Thomas
Already solved. It has to be sent with [... this.props.categories]

Comment: @Cookie please add the "solved" info as an answer

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. I am rolling back your edit for now. Solutions should not be edited into the question.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION IS:

It has to change this.categories1 = this.props.categories; for this.categories1 = [...this.props.categories];